# package ‘ggbiplot’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)?

Tags: r, ggbiplot

Warning in install.packages :

package ‘ggbiplot’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)

tried every options I found to install this package. is it not available to this version of R? have I other way to use ggbiplot on my RStudio?

Comment: Are you sure that's on CRAN? Maybe you need to install from Github / zip?

Comment: did not work:
> install.packages("F:/ggbiplot-master.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/CASA/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Comment: In that case, please add all the relevant information in your answer.

Comment: ggbiplot is not on CRAN; use devtools::install_github.

Comment: Nelson, I checked that.

Comment: Hong:
> library("devtools", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.5")
> library("githubinstall", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.5")
> devtools::install_github(ggbiplot)
Error in lapply(repo, github_remote, ref = ref, subdir = subdir, auth_token = auth_token,  : 
  object 'ggbiplot' not found
>

Comment: JJJ, is it possible that ggbiplot do not run under 3.5.3 R version? should I try an older version?

Warning in install.packages : package ‘ggbiplot’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)

Comment: See my hint below about the 10 dependent packages. Make sure you have all those. Check it one by one. Load them. Once you have them, try `install_github()` again.

Comment: that is it !) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per its repository's [README.md under *Installation*](https://github.com/vqv/ggbiplot#installation), you need

```r
library(devtools)
install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
```

*Edit:* Based on your comment, I am running this now in a fresh Docker container of `r-base`.  It works without a hitch:

```r
> library(devtools)                         
> install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")                                              
Downloading GitHub repo vqv/ggbiplot@master  
[...stuff deleted here for brevity...]
* installing *source* package ‘ggbiplot’ ...
** R
** data
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (ggbiplot)
>
```

So it works as I claimed it would. In between, it required another little diversion as this package apparently is not part of the [tinyverse](http://www.tinyverse.org/) either requiring all this:

```
Installing 10 packages: colorspace, ggplot2, gtable, labeling, 
munsell, plyr, RColorBrewer, reshape2, scales, viridisLite
```

That notwithstanding, *the original suggestions held* just as promised.

Comment: that is what I did, and received thar answer:
Warning in install.packages :

  package ‘ggbiplot’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)

Comment: The error you quote would come from `install.packages` which is not what what is asked for here.

Comment: inwhat version of R did it run? on 3.5.3?

Comment: Yes. R 3.5.3 on Linux,.

Comment: niiiice Dirk, thanks your patiente; I lack that 10 packs, it seem is working now :) later I will try with real data ;)

Comment: So I think in sum you "just" needed a different argument to `install_github()` to have the other dependencies installed too -- that may be a Windows thing as you are mixing from-source and from-binary installation with this.  For me on Linux it's always from source...

Answer (score 0):

Try this first, it worked for me

```
install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
Sys.setenv(R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS="true")
install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
```